# MySQL syntax for UPDATE + CASE WHEN + EXISTS + SELECT MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case, last-insert-id

**EDIT:** Working now, solution in the bottom of this post.

I have tried to create this query for hours now, without success:

```
UPDATE tasks
SET `Order`=
(
    CASE WHEN
    (
        SELECT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM user_job_tasks ujt
            WHERE ujt.JobID = :jobID AND ujt.TaskID = LAST_INSERT_ID()
        )
    )
    THEN
    (
        SELECT `order` FROM
        (
            SELECT MAX(t.`Order`)+1 AS `Order`
            FROM user_job_tasks ujt
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks t ON ujt.TaskID = t.ID
            WHERE ujt.JobID = :jobID
        ) AS temp
    )
    ELSE
    (
        1
    )
    END
)
WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Now, the point of this is to update ***`tasks`*** table's column `Order` where `ID` equals something (LAST_INSERT_ID() here).

If any records exist in ***`user_job_tasks`*** where `jobID` and `taskID` match the values, I want to set `Order` as the highest value + 1 of `Order` found in ***`user_job_tasks`*** where `jobID` matches the value.

If not, `Order` will be set 1.

I am only getting an error `General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'tasks' for update in FROM clause`. I fail to find anything wrong in the query syntax.

Sorry for confusing explanation, perhaps I should just go to sleep.

---

**Working solution:**

```
UPDATE tasks
SET `Order`=
(
    COALESCE
    (
        (
            SELECT `Order` FROM
            (
                SELECT MAX(t.`Order`)+1 AS `Order`
                FROM user_job_tasks ujt
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks t ON ujt.TaskID = t.ID
                WHERE ujt.JobID = :jobID
            ) AS temp
        ),
        1
    )
)
WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: for starters, you can change `CASE WHEN (SELECT EXISTS(...))` to `CASE WHEN EXISTS(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure this does what you want, but I think it does:

```
UPDATE tasks
     SET `Order`= coalesce((SELECT MAX(t.`Order`) + 1 AS `Order`
                            FROM user_job_tasks ujt JOIN
                                 tasks t
                                 ON ujt.TaskID = t.ID
                            WHERE ujt.JobID = :jobID
                           ), 1)
    WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This just looks for the maximum id (+ 1) for your records and then uses 1 if this doesn't exist.

EDIT:

MySQL doesn't like using the table being updated in a `from` clause.  So the above is correctly stated using a second subquery:

```
UPDATE tasks
     SET `Order`= coalesce((SELECT `Order`
                            FROM (SELECT MAX(t.`Order`) + 1 AS `Order`
                                  FROM user_job_tasks ujt JOIN
                                       tasks t
                                       ON ujt.TaskID = t.ID
                                  WHERE ujt.JobID = :jobID
                                 )
                           ), 1)
    WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This limitation would also apply to your query.

Comment: `You can't specify target table 'tasks' for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: Thank you for `COALESCE`. It worked with wrapping the `SELECT MAX()`... inside same `SELECT` wrapper as my first post has. Apparently `UPDATE` does not like those single `SELECT`s? I have no idea why; if anyone has any explanation for that I would appreciate it. Edited original post for working solution.